# How to use specific item's name in JSON to receive other data from that item

Tags: php, arrays, json

for example, I have this JSON file:

```
[{"name":"Name1",
  "value":24,
  "min":10,
  "max":16,
  "rate":108},

  {"name":"Name2",
    "value":69,
    "min":0,
    "max":6,
    "rate":122}
]
```

and i have decoded it into a array using:

```
$json = json_decode($jsondata, true);
```

now I want to get the value of the 2nd item by using its name for example:

```
echo $json['Name1']['value']
```

instead of

```
echo $json[0]['value']
```

any way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: Iterate over items and check item name.

Comment: You'd need to restructure the data differently.

Comment: This is possible only if your JSON Root Element is a JSONObject and not a JSONArray

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this :

1 - **You create a function that will loop through your array and return the value according to the name**

```
function echoValueByName(array $array, $name) {
    foreach($array as $data) {
        if ($data['name'] == $name) {
            return $data['value'];
        }
    }
    return 'Unknow name : '.$name;
}
```

2 - **Now use it to echo the value by name :**

```
echo echoValueByName($json, 'Name1'); // return 24
echo echoValueByName($json, 'test');  // return Unknow name : test
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this,

```
<?php
$str = '[{"name":"Name1",
  "value":24,
  "min":10,
  "max":16,
  "rate":108},

  {"name":"Name2",
    "value":69,
    "min":0,
    "max":6,
    "rate":122}
]';

$arr = json_decode($str,true);
$result = $arr[array_search('Name2',array_column($arr,"name"))];
echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
```

Here is working [code](http://tpcg.io/M1pMBo).

[array_search](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) - Searches the array for a given value and returns the first corresponding key if successful
[array_column](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) - Return the values from a single column in the input array